# Regex in php- catching 9 types of numbers out of a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I just started coding  and have a little problem with regex in PHP.

I am trying to catch the following number types out of a string.

```
000 000 00 00 -
000 000 00 0 -
000 000 00 -
000.000.00.00 -
000.000.00.0 -
000.000.00 -
0000000000 -
000000000 -
00000000 -
```

And of course the 0 stands for a number between 0-9.

This is the pattern I've tried:

```
$pattern = "/\d{3}[. ]\d{3}[. ]\d{2}[. ]?\d{1-2}?/";
```

Something is wrong here, but I don't understand what?

Can you help me?

Comment: The limiting quantifier is `{1,2}`, not `{1-2}`

Comment: Try [`\b\d{3}([.\h]?)\d{3}\1\d{2}(?:\1\d{1,2})?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/TneMp5/2)

Comment: What is wrong here?  What does it match? What doesn't it match?  also is the space and `-` at the end required, it's not in your pattern?

Comment: Wow. Super pattern. And so quick! The space was required and the - wasn't.

Comment: Also, I find online regex testers invaluable for testing/debugging regex expressions.  For example, https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: I personally like to use https://regexr.com/ to test and figure out regular expressions, it gives useful information close at hand

Comment: What is wrong with the solution below?

Comment: Its all good now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should have asked me via a comment about why it does not work, I thought it was clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
/\b\d{3}([.\s]?)\d{3}\1\d{2}(?:\1\d{1,2})?\b/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TneMp5/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (if the numbers can be glued to letters or `_` remove this or replace with `(?<!\d)`)
- `\d{3}` - 3 digits
- `([.\s]?)`  - an optional `.` or whitespace, 1 or 0 times, captured into Group 1
- `\d{3}` - 3 digits
- `\1` - same value as in Group 1
- `\d{2}` - 2 digits
- `(?:\1\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\1` - same value as in Group 1
  - `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary (remove/replace `(?!\d)` depending on the actual requirements).

In PHP:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('test.txt');
$pattern = '/\b\d{3}([.\s]?)\d{3}\1\d{2}(?:\1\d{1,2})?\b/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $results);
print_r($results);
```

Mind the single quotes around the pattern: if you use double quotes instead, you will have to double the backslashes (at least with `\1`) because `"\1"` defines a char with an octal number 1 while `'\1'` will be parsed as a backslash and `1`.